# Bcrypt.Net.Verify returns true on false string data

Tags: c#, .net, bcrypt.net

i'm using a string with salt data to Hash a password using BCrypt.Net library.

code:

```
string src = Salt + UserName + Key + Password
var hash = Bc.HashPassword(src, 12);
```

When i'm trying to verify the hashed data with a wrong string data (different password for example) , the value `BCrypt.Verify(wrongStr,hash)` returns is `true`.

Any Ideas? 
is there any String's Length Limits?

Answer (score 2):

bcrypt returns a 60 char string 
make sure that your filed can handle that

and your verification is wrong you need to utilize boolean!

```
string myPassword = "password";
string mySalt = BCrypt.GenerateSalt();
//mySalt == "$2a$10$rBV2JDeWW3.vKyeQcM8fFO"
string myHash = BCrypt.HashPassword(myPassword, mySalt);
//myHash == "$2a$10$rBV2JDeWW3.vKyeQcM8fFO4777l4bVeQgDL6VIkxqlzQ7TCalQvla"


bool doesPasswordMatch = BCrypt.CheckPassword(myPassword, myHash);
```